# How to get rid of fullCalendar scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I wrapped the `<div id="calendar"></div>` area.

As follows:

```
<div id="calendarContainer">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

After that, I modified the width and height of the `#calendarContainer` to 500px x 500px.

From now on, I will explain what I want to do with pictures.

[image]

I want to change the picture above as shown below.

[image]

How do I fix css?

I'd like to remove the side scrolling as much as possible.

p.s) I did the following work. As a result, the scrolling is gone, but the heat is broken.

```
.fc-scroller { overflow-y: hidden !important; }
```

[image]

Comment: keep height as auto?

Comment: @Hash aumm..? I don't understand

Comment: @Hash The name of the corresponding class is fc-scroller.

Comment: hav u tried `.fc-scroller {
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
}`

Comment: @Hash To implement what I want, you can touch these three options. (overflow-x , overflow-y, height)

Comment: Oh, I will check. wait please.

Comment: The value for the result is disastrous.

Comment: @Hash please check this link :  https://imgur.com/a/qQRFJ

Comment: im confused now, isnt that what your looking for? `I'd like to remove the side scrolling`

Comment: Your right. but when you look at the picture, you can see that the heat is broken.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161525/discussion-between-seongwon-and-hash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hacky but maybe is the best you can achieve. The idea is to override the styles.

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();
```

```css
#calendarContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.fc-scroller {
  height: auto !important;
}

.fc-head .fc-widget-header {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.fc-scroller {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendarContainer">
  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: After 30 seconds, please see my answer.

Comment: It works as a result of applying the parts you give me. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you a question related to the fullCalendar function?

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer solved it, but ok :) I will be happy to help. If this question could help to other people, please ask in a `ask question` and paste the link in a comment. If not, please contact me via my LinkedIn profile (in my profile page).

Comment: OK I will check

Comment: Feu, please check link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897288/how-to-display-a-specific-month-in-fullcalendar

Answer (score 1):

I solve that.

delete `.fc-scroller {overflow-y: hidden! important; }`

And added the code.

```
body 
{
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

It's very well work.