# How to display a specific month in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have two columns with a type value of date in one table.
(1.ri_startDate , 2.ri_endDate)

These two columns store different dates.

```
ri_startDate > 2017-12-3
ri_endDate > 2018-3-4
```

When displaying fullCalendar I would like to display the month based on these two values.

To put it easily,

"2017-December, 2018-January,February,March"

I would like to display only four months.
(Other months prevent the expression)

How do implement this?

Tell us what you think.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927744/fullcalendar-limit-the-display-of-available-months

Is this the sort of functionality you're looking for?

Comment: Similar but not. If we display fullCalendar, will not we start with today's date? @JakeBoomgaarden

Comment: However, I would like to display the calendar based on ri_startDate. @JakeBoomgaarden

Comment: For example, if ri_startDate is 2018-March, when you display fullCalendar, you want to display it from 2018-March, not today's date. @JakeBoomgaarden

Comment: makes sense. I think you'd want to do something like this then... 
`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 year: 2012,
 month: 4,
 date: 25
});  // This will initialize for May 25th, 2012.`
(taken from SO question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174744/how-to-set-full-calendar-to-a-specific-start-date-when-its-initialized-for-the )

Comment: so you can just take the date you have from your database, and parse it out into the year/month/day, then set those values on full calendar creation

Comment: It's good plan :) But is there anything else I need to refer to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161562/discussion-between-jake-boomgaarden-and-seongwon).

Comment: @Seongwon have you get an answer?

Comment: @MoshFeu OH, Feu, I see you. It's get answer but I have different problem.

Comment: @Seongwon. Ok, what is it?

Comment: If you can, check out this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899120/why-uncaught-typeerror-fullcalendar-is-not-a-function/47899977?noredirect=1#comment82767016_47899977

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for caring me.

Comment: :) Sure. That's why we here.. I see that there are people that already help you with it. If you will need more help, tell me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161582/discussion-between-seongwon-and-mosh-feu).

Comment: @MoshFeu If you can, let me chat 1:1