# Why Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I imported it as below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/locale/ko.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fcImportantCSS.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminMainPage.css">
```

And I wrote the following.

HTML:

```
<div id="calendarContainer" style="display:none">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="ri_startDate">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="ri_endDate">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// fullCalendar 관련
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    center: "title", // 센터에는 타이틀 명이 오고
    left: "prev", // 왼쪽에는 < 버튼이 오고
    right: "next" // 오른쪽에는 > 버튼이 오게됌
  },
  lang: 'ko', // 달력 한글 설정
  editable: true, // 달력의 이벤트를 수정할 수 있는지 여부를 결정
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, view) // 일 클릭시 발생
  {
    var dateFormat = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if (confirm('휴진으로 등록 하시겠습니까?')) {

    } else {
      alert('bye ~ ');
    }
  }
});
```

It worked well when tested, but it does not work right now.

The following error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

Why do I get this error?

How do I fix the code to catch this error?

I need your help, and Please tell me your opinion.

Comment: where did u write ur code? within same page? it seem that it not able to found the fullcalendar.js, did the path is correct? check your console network tab

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with the route. @Se0ng11

Comment: are you write the code within document ready? just by looking at ur script, I not able to see any wrong, but from the error, it just point that it cannot find the fullcalendar, did the fullcalendar show in the network tab?

Comment: No, it's exactly what I posted to JS.

Comment: so u write in a JS file? which 1 is ur JS file?

Comment: write in a JS file? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161571/discussion-between-se0ng11-and-seongwon).

Comment: Check your browsers console's source tab to verify fullcalendar js loaded or not

Comment: @NitinDhomse It will load normally.

Comment: @Seongwon : Is the fullcalendar js loaded there or not?

Comment: @NitinDhomse yeah, please check link : https://imgur.com/a/N6cRa

Comment: Initialize you fullcalendar plugin inside document.reay()

Comment: Why importing two jquery library? try use only one

Comment: @RDev I just tried to run it, but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: @RDev I deleted jquery.3.1.1 Why is it being imported?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the follwing.

```js
$(function(){
// fullCalendar 관련
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    center: "title", // 센터에는 타이틀 명이 오고
    left: "prev", // 왼쪽에는 < 버튼이 오고
    right: "next" // 오른쪽에는 > 버튼이 오게됌
  },
  lang: 'ko', // 달력 한글 설정
  editable: true, // 달력의 이벤트를 수정할 수 있는지 여부를 결정
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, view) // 일 클릭시 발생
  {
    var dateFormat = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    if (confirm('휴진으로 등록 하시겠습니까?')) {

    } else {
      alert('bye ~ ');
    }
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/gcal.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fullcalendar/1.5.4/fullcalendar.print.css"  rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id = "calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161581/discussion-on-answer-by-nitin-dhomse-why-uncaught-typeerror-fullcalendar).